# Is my friend from Egypt with a Schengen visa allowed to visit the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, egyptian-citizens, german-residents

I've been living in the UK for 11 years. I want to know if it is possible that one of my friends who is from Egypt but is working in Europe for the past nine years and has a Schengen visa is allowed to visit the UK. On GOV they are saying that it is allowed.

Comment: No he isn't allowed into UK if he still posses a visa to work(stay) in Germany and not an European citizen. He needs an UK visa to enter UK.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible, though he will need a separate visa for the UK than the schengen visa. Its a well known problem for many non-EU people in the UK/I or mainland Europe that they can't easily go to the other one.

Since he is working in Germany, can prove he is settled there, etc... he shouldn't have any problems getting the visa. But he still has to go through the application process, which might be annoying.

Answer (score 7):

Having residency in a Schengen country does not allow entry to the UK. Entering the information from your question into the UK government's site to check whether a visa is required shows that your friend [will need a UK visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/egypt/tourism/no).

Comment: Thank you, Chris. The trouble is that on GOV, when I complete all that formular, they told me that he is aloud just because we have an adress over there and we are living there as well. I am so confused! I will see..

Comment: I'm not sure how you're filling the form, but unless your question is missing some important information you must have made a mistake. Your address certainly doesn't affect whether or not your friend needs a visa, and the form doesn't ask for that information when I fill it based on the information from your question. At the bottom of my link you can see how I filled the form - are any of the answers I chose wrong? (There's no specific option for visiting friends as the purpose of visit, but it is considered as "tourism" for the purpose of this form)

Comment: @Leontina Are you answering ‘yes’ to the question: Will you be travelling with or visiting either your partner or a family member in the UK? What is your official relationship status (‘friend’? ‘Living together’?) and what type of Schengen visa does your friend have? Is it an Article 10 residency card for example https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card?